# Performance difference NTFS Linux and NTFS Windows

Tags: windows, ntfs

I need to format a disk to install Windows 8 on it (single boot). I cannot do it from Windows (I have only Ubuntu for now). 
So my questions are:

Will the disk formatted to NTFS with Ubuntu be slower than if I had formatted it to NTFS from Windows (the drivers are not the same as far as I know) ?

Or can I just simply format to NTFS from the Windows 8 dvd ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drivers might not be the same but a formatted NTFS partition is a formatted NTFS partition. What ever the tool you use.

By the way: The Ubuntu driver is for mounting and writing to a NTFS partition already formatted as NTFS. In general you format a disk from the [GParted software](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), not Ubuntu itself (though you can install GParted in Ubuntu and use it from there). If the GParted NTFS formatting tool was not up to standard Windows would consider it a corrupted file system and refuse to start from it.

> Or can I just simply format to NTFS from the Windows 8 dvd ?

That question is off topic ... but the answer is: of course. You can format from any installation media since one of the 1st things to do is to set up your partition for a file system structure that that system needs to run on.

Comment: Of course, sorry i did not see I can just erase the partition.

Comment: @Gonzague oh yes that too. Windows probably will silently install in the unallocated partition.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't make a difference what OS you format your partition on, although it is generally advisable to use Windows for formatting partitions with Windows-specific file systems.

But: There certainly is a performance difference between using NTFS partitions on Linux and Windows. While Windows uses a native kernel driver, i.e. a very performant low-level driver, Linux uses `NTFS-3G` which runs in userspace, i.e. on a 'higher level', and is as such inherently slower.

Some of these performance differences can be ameliorated by following the recommendations listed in the Tuxera [NTFS-3G FAQ](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#highcpu), the [`big_writes` option](http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29900) in particular, but I haven't been able to reach Windows-level NTFS performance on Linux so far.

---

Further reading:

[NTFS drive mounted generates huge load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93906/ntfs-drive-mounted-generates-huge-load)

https://superuser.com/questions/613869/ntfs-write-speed-really-slow-15mb-s-on-ubuntu

https://superuser.com/questions/204000/are-there-faster-solutions-for-ntfs-on-linux-than-ntfs-3g